# SQLCacheDependency with ADO.NET Entity Model

Tags: ado.net

Does SQL Cache Dependency work with the ADO.NET Entity Model? Please give me some example link of something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an msdn link to [SqlCacheDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx)

and here's for [LINQ & SqlCacheDependency](http://www.andrewdothay.net/blog/2009/01/28/LINQAndTheSqlCacheDependency.aspx)

Comment: @Rashmi Pandit Even i want to implement the caching for Entity Framewotk but as far as i know SqlCacheDependency does not support Entity Framework and the articles you provided resembles Linq to Sql and not Linq to Entity

Answer (score 0):

But linq and ADO.Net are'nt not really the same thing